Equilibrium strategy in a sequential all pay auction
Suppose $n$ players are taking part in an auction where the prize is a $\$100$ bill. At each time point all players can choose to either pass or make a bid which has to be at least the previous highest bid + $\$1$ but can be higher (or $\$1$ if there have been no bids yet). The numbers are revealed simultaneously and they become that person's current bid from the end of that round onwards. The bidding ends when we've had a round where nobody places a bid.
At the end of the auction everyone pays their bid and the highest bidder wins the $\$100$ bill, so its a type of all pay auction. I was wondering what an optimal strategy looks like  for a player of such a game. I've seen the Wikipedia page on all pay auctions where they talk about something like this but only in the case where there is one round and people who got outbid on the first round don't have a chance to raise their bid and become leaders any more so it's not exactly the same.
I have some intuitive guesses about what might be a decent way to play this game as well as can work out some basic things like e.g. if after a round you're the leading bidder you don't raise your bid in the next round because that just guarantees the game continues and you'll be paying more now but haven't made much non-trivial progress on coming up with a good strategy that makes mathematical sense.
My intuitions are along the line of a strategy where you only ever bid with probability on the order of $1/n$ (you decide this before the first round even happens) and if you get overbid by someone then in the next round you raise by a large amount like $20 to dissuade them from overbidding you again etc. However I'm not able to formalize any of this and so I thought I'd ask over here to get other people's ideas on what makes a good strategy for a player of this game.

I'd start with small cases: take $n=2$ and a 1 dollar bill for example, then if you can prove something for that increase $n$ or the value of the prize.

At first, I thought you wrote the prize was $100 billion!  The person with the largest bankroll has an advantage, since that person can afford to lose the most.  One strategy for $100 would be to bid $99 immediately, if it's available, otherwise don't bid.  Presumably, no one would bid $100, since they would not make any money.  After reading about all pay auctions, it sounds like people tend to lose money over time.  The optimal strategy is probably to not bid at all!

What happens if there are ties for the highest bidder? For example, everyone could bet $99 in the first round.

In that case we can run the auction one more round and if nobody improves the bid then the money gets evenly divided between every single highest bidder.

Wow!  This is not an attractive auction.  It's designed so that the auction house or seller make out like a bandit.  It feels like texas holdem poker, since the strategy will depend heavily on the strategies of the other bidders.  I stick with the "don't play" strategy.

But if everyone decides to go for "don't play" then you can get yourself a $100 bill for only $1. Hence, the pure "don't play" isn't a stable equilibrium.

Right!  In a cooperative game theory setting, the players might take turns bidding a dollar, and no one else bids.  I think you have the answer, although someone new will come along and upset the apple cart :-)
